# C# - How to POST List

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So I have this code that POST a `JSON data` to my `REST API` using c#

```
try
    {
        tempquantityofmenu = entQuantity.Text;
        CustList custo = new CustList();

        CustomerOrder custo1 = new CustomerOrder()
           {
              menu_name = tempnameofmenu,
              menu_quantity = tempquantityofmenu,
              menu_code = tempcodeofmenu
            };

        custo.CUSTOMER_ORDER.Add(custo1);

        await Navigation.PushAsync(new OrdernowCategory());
       }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            DisplayAlert("error", ex.ToString(), "OK");
        }
```

Then I am getting this `System.NullReferenceExeption: Object Reference not set to an instance of an object`

```
public class CustomerOrder
{
    public string menu_name { get; set; }
    public string menu_quantity { get; set; }
    public string menu_code { get; set; }
}

public class CustList
{
    public List<CustomerOrder> CUSTOMER_ORDER { get; set; }
}
```

I think my problem here is that when adding a item to the `CUSTOMER_ORDER` inside the `try catch` is not working

Answer (score 3):

You can either

```
public class CustList
{
    public List<CustomerOrder> CUSTOMER_ORDER { get; set; } = new List<CustomerOrder>();
}
```

or

```
public class CustList
{
    public List<CustomerOrder> CUSTOMER_ORDER { get; set; } 

    public CustList()
    {
        CUSTOMER_ORDER = new List<CustomerOrder>();
    }
}
```

or

```
custo.CUSTOMER_ORDER = new List<CustomerOrder>();
custo.CUSTOMER_ORDER.Add(custo1);
```

And for the love of all things neat and tidy in this world, don't name your variables/properties/or andything with capitals and underscores

Answer (score 3):

Because you didn't create an instance for `CUSTOMER_ORDER` property, `CUSTOMER_ORDER` is reference types, which have `null` values by default.

If you want to solve it you can give `CUSTOMER_ORDER` an instance collection like this.

```
CustList custo = new CustList() { 
     CUSTOMER_ORDER = new List<CustomerOrder>() 
};
```